# Links between homological algebra and algebraic number theory

Tags: research

Can  I   find    some  interesting   applications   of  homological  algebra  in algebraic  number  theory?   I  need   some  references. Thank   you  in   advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in *Galois cohomology*, which in my opinion is a very beautiful subject. As always, a good place to start is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_cohomology. Another good reference is a book of Serre's called *Cohomologie Galoisienne* which has an english translation published by Springer.

Comment: It  is   advanced   for  a   first  year master  student?

Comment: @rafa for a graduate student without the necessary background the Serre book may be prohibitive. There are these notes of William Stein of Washington University (link: http://wstein.org/edu/2010/582e/lectures/all/galois_cohomology.pdf) which may be more appropriate.